# Need assistance with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I would like to validate url's in javascript before user proceeds further.

**The urls below should match;**

- `http://google.com`
- `http://www.google.com`
- `www.google.com`
- `google.com`

And not match;

- `http://google`
- `http://www.google`
- `www.google`
- `google`

Please help me im really bad at regex

Comment: what are you trying to do? what have you tried so far? please have a look at (ask)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
     var urlR = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)
       (?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
     var url= content.match(urlR);
```

or

```
  var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

     if(regex.test("http://google.com")){
      alert("Successful match");
    }else{
    alert("No match");
      }
```